# Create a redirect rule for Azure CDN in Verizon which adds /index.html to the end of URL

Tags: regex, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I created an Azure CDN under Verizon Premium Subscription in the Azure portal with an endpoint which points to my Azure Static Website URL.
I want to create a redirect rule in Azure Verizon engine which adds `/index.html` to the end of URL if no extension is specified or the last sing of URL is not a `/` symbol.
So far I tried to use `(.+\/[^\.]\w+$)` regex expression, you can see an example of how it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/XKmret/1/)

**My first approach:**
[image: 1st approach]

In this case, if you type the URL https://blah.com/foo/bar in the web browser
it doesn't change the URL however you are able to view some of the content of the existing file from https://blah.com/foo/bar/index.html but some of the links to resources are broken. Not sure why I'm not getting the 404 in this case but maybe its because that I set the `Index document name` to `index.html` in the `Static Website` panel in the `Storage account` panel in Azure. If I open the `Network` tab in the developer tools of `Chrome` I can see a lot of 404 responses e.g. 
[image: 404 resources]
And its because the website tries to get resources from the `https://blah.com/foo/` directory instead of `https://blah.com/foo/bar/`
So, for example, the `loadcsh.js` in fact is located under the `https://blah.com/foo/bar/loadcsh.js` but the website is searching for the file under the wrong directory `https://blah.com/foo/loadcsh.js`

**My second approach**
[image]
In this case, if you type the URL `https://blah.com/foo/bar`
it makes a redirect to `https://blah.com/foo/bar/foo/bar/index.html`
so the `foo/bar/` is redundant here.

**My third approach** 
[image]
In this case, if you type the URL `https://blah.com/foo/bar` 
it makes a redirect to `https://blah.com/index.html`

I have no idea how to apply the rule which makes a redirect from `https://blah.com/foo/bar`
to `https://blah.com/foo/bar/index.html` and is generic for all such cases.
Any ideas??
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Regex expression is ok. You can add the rule `URL redirect`, in the *Source* textbox you type your Regex expression `(.+\/[^\.]\w+$)` and in the *Destination* textbox add `https://%{host}/$1/index.htm`. Here I used the HTTP variable for Azure CDN which can be used in Verizon. You can read more about the variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-http-variables#definitions).
In short words the `%{host}` returns a host name e.g. `www.contoso.com`

Please keep in mind all rule changes will require couple of hours propagation before it takes an effect on the CDN.